# How can I bypass a recursive function-definition in a shell function?

Tags: shell, zsh

I want to add a function like the following to my `.zshrc`:

```
rg() { rg "$@" --pretty less -XFRS ;}
```

Problem is, this causes an infinite loop upon invocation.

I *thought* that single-quoting the command's name (`'rg' --pretty …`) bypassed locally-defined functions and aliases; but that failed to prevent the infinite-loop, for some reason.

I can implement this with an absolute path,

```
rg() { /usr/local/bin/rg "$@" --pretty less -XFRS ;}
```

… but I don't want to lose `$PATH`-resolution of the program; I *just* want to bypass the function.

Comment: Note that this, actually, *could* be a use-case for aliases; all you are doing is adding a pair of options to a command. `alias rg='rg --pretty less -XFRS'`. (Unless you want to make sure the `--pretty less` overrides any `--pretty` option that may be provided by the user.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `command` builtin:

```
rg() { command rg "$@" --pretty less -XFRS ;}
```

This runs given `COMMAND` with `ARGS` suppressing  shell function lookup, or display information about the specified COMMANDs.

Comment: Seems to solve the problem! I was aware of `command`, but I didn't know that it functioned any differently than shell-quoting the name. Thanks!